# Representing polymorphism in Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have an abstract parent class `Server` and 3 subclasses `InternalServer`, `ExternalServer` and `LoggableInternalServer`. `Server` has the public abstract method `receiveClient()`.

The application has a list of `Server` which contains a number of objects of the three aforementioned types. This list is iterated and the `receiveClient()` method is called in each iteration. The implementation of `receiveClient()` varies depending on the subclass.

Is there a way to represent this polymorphic behaviour using a Sequence Diagram? If not, what other diagram could I use to document this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to represent this polymorphic behavior using a Sequence Diagram. The polymorphic invocations are modeled by multiples scenarios controlled by the guard conditions. Therefore, for each polymorphic scenario, the dynamic binding (polymorphic invocation) is represented for a "scenario box". So, this is a single diagram to show polymorphic invocations for your question.

[image]

So, even though this model to answer your question, it is not a clear solution, because it is not-trivial to represent polymorphism in a sequence diagram. Finally, a similar discussion is on the question [How to visualize polymorphic invocations in a single diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099461/how-to-visualize-polymorphic-invocations-in-a-single-diagram/25130687#25130687).

Answer (score 2):

You could start the lifeline at point of object creation showing a message from the sender that creates the instance of the classifier.  You could mix this with an ALT fragment to show the different implementations.